# Using 'case function' inside 'ON' clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that I need to join.

Table1 has columns id, Name, idObject, lineItem.
Table2 has columns id, City, idLineItem, idOrder, idSupplier, idAdv.
Table3 has columns idAdv, State.

My query is:

```
select Table1.id, Table1.Name, Table1.idObject, Table2.City, Table3.State
from Table1 
join Table2 ON case 
                 when Table1.Name='abc' then Table1.idObject=Table2.idLineItem
                 when Table1.Name='def' then Table1.idObject=Table2.idOrder
                 else Table1.idObject=Table2.idSupplier
               end
join Table3 on Table2.idAdv=Table3.idAdv
group by Table1.id, Table1.idObject;
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: Even if this works with a `case` statement, or other logic, it is a query endemic of bad database schema design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CASE statement can only return a single value, so you have to move your comparison outside of the CASE. Something like this:

```
select Table1.id, Table1.Name, Table1.idObject, Table2.City, Table3.State
from Table1 
join Table2 ON Table1.idObject = case 
                 when Table1.Name='abc' then Table2.idLineItem
                 when Table1.Name='def' then Table2.idOrder
                 else Table2.idSupplier
               end
join Table3 on Table2.idAdv=Table3.idAdv
group by Table1.id, Table1.idObject;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the OP case statements return a proper boolean type as the result of the comparisons?

Comment: Those aren't boolean comparisons, they're join conditions, they don't return anything.

Comment: If he wanted to do boolean comparison, he'd need to do something like join Table2 on 1 = case when Table1.name='abc' and Table1.idObject = Table2.idLineItem then 1 case when .. etc... else 0 end.

Comment: The comparison operator `=` returns `true` or `false` no matter where it is.  The case statement faithfully returns the value calculated after the `then` on the lucky `when`.  Granted I like your syntax more, but it seems like either should work or not work.  Are you sure this works?

Comment: No, you're correct, both syntax work, I've never seen them built that way (I use MSSQL mostly and only dabble in MySQL, the query as written in the post is a syntax error in MSSQL.)

Comment: I really hate having `case` statements return boolean values too, and there really may be some vendor specific value casting issue at play in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly..

```
select Table1.id, Table1.Name, Table1.idObject, Table2.City, Table3.State 
from Table1 
join Table2 ON
   (Table1.Name='abc' and Table1.idObject=Table2.idLineItem) 
OR (Table1.Name='def' and Table1.idObject=Table2.idOrder) 
OR (Table1.Name <> 'abc' and Table1.Name <> 'def' and Table1.idObject=Table2.idSupplier) 
join Table3 on Table2.idAdv=Table3.idAdv 
group by Table1.id, Table1.idObject;
```

Better check the execution plan though.